# ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I am getting below error on,

```
ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

version details, [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

```
cqlsh:infinito> select count(id) from list_subscriber;
```

This table contains only 10 lacks of records, and primary key is on 'Id' column only having int type.

I am trying to increase some timeout params `(request_timeout_in_ms:)` but no luck

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up doing below options, increased below options value by 10 times.

edited /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml file

```
sudo nano /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 50000
# How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 100000
# How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
# How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 50000
# How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
# that contends with other proposals for the same row
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 10000
# How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
# (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
# we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 600000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 100000

# How long before a node logs slow queries. Select queries that take longer than
# this timeout to execute, will generate an aggregated log message, so that slow queries
# can be identified. Set this value to zero to disable slow query logging.
slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 5000
```

And then opened terminal and executed below command

```
cqlsh --request-timeout=6000
```

Everything looks ok.